# Let $\tau = (1 2)(3 4 5)$. Does there exist an $n$-cycle $σ$ (where $n \ge 5$) such that $\tau=\sigma^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, permutation-cycles

Let $\tau = (1 2)(3 4 5)$. Does there exist an $n$-cycle $σ$ (where $n \ge 5$) such that $\tau=\sigma^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$?

I was trying to solve it using the orders of permutations,
$$
O( \sigma ) = n \\
O(\tau) = 6 = O(\sigma^k)
$$
But I am not reaching anywhere.

Comment: What do you know about the powers of an $n$-cycle in general?  (If the answer is "not much", then it might be helpful to try out some examples.  For example, try taking the powers of a 10-cycle to 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc., and see if you see any patterns in the results.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler so I was trying taking the powers, I believe the result we'll get is O(sigma^k) = O(sigma)/gcd(O(sigma),k), I can't understand how exactly will this be helpful here.

Comment: I'm not sure if overall order of permutations will necessarily be useful in solving the problem.  Is there anything else you notice about the powers (for example, try looking at the cycle decompositions of the powers)?

Comment: The number of cycle decompositions will be gcd(O(sigma),k)(=n) and will be disjoint. And maybe something on the lines of the first n elements will be part of different cycles.

Comment: OK, what I'm getting at is: if you take any power of a single cycle, then in the cycle decomposition of that power, all the cycles have the same size.  (More specifically, along the lines of what you were writing: if you take the $k$th power of an $n$-cycle, then the cycle decomposition has $\gcd(k, n)$ components, each of size $n / \gcd(k, n)$.)

Comment: Aah yes, so that will trivially prove the result, thhanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139233/discussion-between-atom-bomb-and-daniel-schepler).

Answer (score 0):

To get a $2$-cycle times a $3$-cycle from the $k$-th power of an $n$-cycle, we'll need $n=2(k\pmod n)$ and $n=3(k \pmod n)$. So we'd need $k\equiv 0\pmod n$, which gives $\sigma ^k=e$.  Thus it's not possible.

Comment: Can you explain how you'd get n=2(k(mod n)).

Comment: Well,  it's $k\pmod n$, because the order of an $n$-cycle is $n$.  Then it's $2(k\pmod n)$ (and $3(k\pmod n)$) because when you raise a cycle to a power $k$, you sort of "jump" $k$ places.  So for instance to get a $2$-cycle, you need to get back where you started after jumping twice by $k$.  For a $3$-cycle the reasoning is similar: you need to get back where you start after $3$ jumps.

Comment: Got it, thanks!